# Thermador oven timer not beeping

Tags: timer

I have a Thermador pro grand range. All of a sudden, the timer has stopped beeping when the time gets to zero. It says it is finished, but no sound. It still beeps to let me know that the oven has reached temperature, so I know the beeper is still, working, just not for the timer...

Comment: maybe you disabled the timer chime

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'd go with @jsotola's guess; let us know if it's right. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same issue and my alerts are set max.  my phone app alerts, but no local sound...

I got it to work by simply turning off the circuit breaker for 30 seconds and back on. All the sounds returned to normal.

Comment: The original question is about a Thermador oven, not a phone.

Comment: I got it to work by simply turning off the circuit breaker for 30 seconds and back on.  All the sounds returned to normal.

Comment: I added your comment (which answers the question to a point) to your answer... which should change the answer from a comment to an answer... and prevent it from being closed...hopefully.